# Why Scripts Keep Running even if file doesn't exist?

Tags: php

I was running a script in my browser which insert like some 100000 records in database. For some reason I deleted the file in which I have written script but it was little surprising for me that the scripts keeps inserting the records in the database even when the script doesn't exist. Why is that?

Comment: Its is cached in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a request is made to the web-server:

- The PHP file is loaded into memory, it gets compiled and is running.
- Since the file is in memory, any changes to file on disk is not applicable to running file.

If that strikes another question in you, as to "*Why the hell it gets loaded into memory ?? Why can't it be executed from the disk directly ?*":

- Memory here is mostly the RAM, which is faster in doing read/write which is the need to compete with processors speed.
- HardDisk is a slow memory and therefore, accessing from it, would make your programs very slow to execute.

To match with processors speed, there comes a need for a executable file to be loaded from Slow Memory (Often HardDisks) to a faster memory (Often Ram, or processor's cache sometimes).

And therefore, the reason and answer, as to why your file on disk is not in sync file in memory.

*Also please be assured, that this would be working fine in your next request!!*

But if you still want to do it immediately, you can consider stopping/restart your Apache/IIS (whichever applicable) Server, as this will kill the process immediately.

Answer (score 4):

The process is executing **in memory** not from disk.

If you wish to stop a running script, you will need to restart your webserver, or kill the php process. Depending on whether it was running from the command line or not.

Answer (score 0):

@Umair once you run the script then request go to the server and it'll run on server until process complete . so it doen't matter if file is available or not because it's old request which is under process that's why this happening.